# Return different number of variables depending on the caller

Tags: python, return

Is it possible in python for a function to return a different number of variables depending on the caller?

I am a Matlab programmer and in this language it's used a lot, but I was wondering if python also have this option and if it's a good programming practice.

Matlab example:

```
minval      = min([5,2,7,1,6])   % will only return the min value
minval, idx = min([5,2,7,1,6])   % will return the min value and the index
```

The min function here is just an example (my function has nothing to do with calculating min values).

I want to create a function which in 90% of the cases only the first returned value will be used (like in `min`, where sometimes you don't care about the index but only want the value itself).

Of course I can force to be called with 2 returning values every time, but I think it will be cleaner and nicer if you can call it with only one return or with 2 depending on your needs.

I have seen some interesting proposals about passing a flag with a default value to tell the function how many outputs are expected, but I was looking for something completely transparent.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Worth doing? No.

Comment: many functions (for example in web API) always returns list - with many results, with one result or empty list if there is no results - it makes life easier.

Comment: There is nothing "clean" or "nice" about how MATLAB handles returned values.  It makes simple things like wrapper functions a pain, makes things like classes that override indexing a nightmare, and makes things like general-purpose anonymous wrapper functions impossible.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard Python way to do this; a Python function doesn't normally know about the context it was called in.

I'm not going to claim it's *impossible* since there are ways to go back through a stack trace, inspect code objects and so on, who knows, it may be possible some way -- but not in a way you'd want to actually use.

In Python you'd either pass an option with a default value so you don't have to pass it in the normal case:

```
def min(iterable, return_index=False):
    ...

minval = min([5,2,7,1,6])
minval, i = min([5,2,7,1,6], return_index=True)
```

Or you'd always return both, and just ignore one of them:

```
minval, _ = minwithindex([5,2,7,1,6])
```

Comment: Note that `_` does not really "ignore" the corresponding part of the ouput, but `_` is a valid variable name and thus `_` will hold a reference to the index after this statement. Also note that __with python3__ you can unpack multiple values into a list, i.e. if `min` returned three or more values instead of two and you only want to store the first one you could do `minval, *ignore = min(...)`. `ignore` would then hold the remaining values as a list.

Comment: I have exactly this issue with a library that I want to extend. I want to save a raw result while processing packets and then return exactly what is returned today, plus an optional second result with the raw buffer. This way, customer code is not affected at all and there is no upgrade work required. New applications can use either format, just as you show. I consider this not only acceptable, but desirable even for new code. Returning tuples or lists is rather painful when the only issue is an optional extra return result. IMHO at least.

Comment: This is right way. By giving one more argument in function, depending on the value of the new argument, you can get different returns.

Answer (score -2):

Sure you can do it! Just prepare an empy list and use it to receive your different number of values. Look at my example:

```
def foo(number):
    if number < 0:
        return "more","values","returned"
    else:
        return "single value"

num = 5
myList = foo(num)
```